# How to return a Arraylist of String ArrayList in ws webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, marshalling

I wrote a web service like below. It will get list of all userid and username.

```
@WebMethod(operationName="GetUserList")
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getUsers() {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result_t = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        System.out.println("=====Start fetch UserDepID=====");
        
        DataSource tDataSource = null;
        Connection tConnection = null;
        Statement tStatement = null;
        ResultSet tRs = null;
        String orgID = "";
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~Start getOrgID~~~~~~~~~~");
        try {
            tDataSource = getJndiDataSource("java:/DS");
            tConnection = tDataSource.getConnection();
            tStatement = tConnection.createStatement();
            String tSql = "select id,userName from Users where leaveDate is null";
            System.out.println("sql " + tSql);
            tRs = tStatement.executeQuery(tSql);
            while (tRs.next()) {
                orgID = tRs.getString(1);
                System.out.println("orgID " + orgID);
                ArrayList<String> line=new ArrayList<String>();
            //  
                    line.add(tRs.getString(1));
                    line.add(tRs.getString(2));
                    result_t.add(line);
            }
            System.out.println("Query End");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            this.closeDB(tBPMConnection, tBPMStatement, tRs);
        }
        return result_t;
    }
```

It was deployed successfully in wildfly server. But when I tried to test it in soap ui. The result is like below.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:GetUserListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws_query_hr/">
         <return/>
         <return/>
         <return/>
      </ns2:GetUserListResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How do I get the real value of the response? I'm sure the result did contain some values. Thx.
I updated the code to return a List of ArrayList and this time has error

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class java.util.ArrayList unkown
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.ArrayList unknown。
```

Comment: Unrelated: you should prefer interfaces types over implementation classes, and use the the diamond operator. It should be `List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>()`. Also note that you are violating java naming conventions, and hungarian notation is strongly strongly discouraged these days, esp in Java!

Comment: And just for debugging purposes: dont populate your result from the DB. Just hardcode such a list with known values, and then debug that. Fetching data from the db, and sending out a list of lists on your web interface are two different problems. So solve them separately, and only when you know both things work, bring it together.

Comment: And regarding your actual problem: the code looks okay on a first glance ... so I would check the logs to ensure that it gets actually called as you expect it, and probably do even more logging and so on.

Comment: result_t.add(line); Make a system.out.println(line) and let us know what get's printed

Comment: @Boug. I added  System.out.println(result_t.get(0).get(0));     and it has some value. I guess maybe I need to define the return XML format?

Comment: The exception is a good hint, check if your WS runtime actually allows ArrayList<?> as a return type, or if you need to provide some marshall/unmarshall class. In your shoes I would define  a JavaBean holding the 2 strings and return a simple YourStringBean [] - Don't really remember clearly but I think I faced the same issue, althou ages ago and with AXIS...